# Log in system doesn't recognize me as 'logged in'

Tags: php, session

I'm busy on a log-in system, and when I wanted to test it, I registered. That worked. My login details are inserted in the DB, works like a charm. Then the `register()` function passes my details on to the `login()` function, which logges me in, and redirects me to the index page.

That part all works, but when I want to check if I'm truely logged in by checking if the `$_SESSION` variable is set, but it doesn't show that it is.

This is the function that preforms the logging in:

```
public function login()
    {
        $postusername = $_POST['username'];
        $postpassword = $_POST['passwordp'];
        $this->errors = array();
        $query = $this->db->conn->prepare('SELECT naam, pass, email FROM ht_users WHERE naam = ?');
        $query->bind_param('s', $postusername);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($username, $password, $email);
        $query->store_result();
        if ($query->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($query->fetch()) 
            {
                if (password_verify($postpassword, $password))
                {
                    //$sessionid = $this->newSession($username);
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['user'] = array(
                        'username' => $username,
                        'email' => $email
                    );
                    header('Location: index.php');
                    exit();
                } 
                    else 
                {
                    $this->errors[] = 'Invalid Password';
                }
            }
        }
            else
        {
            $this->errors[] = 'Username/email not found NIGGUH';
        }
        return $this->errors;
        exit();
        $query->close();
    }
```

As you can see; when the login is successful it starts a session, sets the `$_SESSION` variable then it redirects me to `index.php`. To preform a simple 'am I logged in' check, I used the menu:

```
                    <?php
                    if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
                    {
                        ?><ul class="submenu-holder">
                                <li><a href="login.php">Inloggen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="register.php">Registreren</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Gebruikerslijst</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Alle badges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Wachtwoord vergeten</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    <?php
                    }
                        else
                    {
                    ?><ul class="submenu-holder">
                                <li>INGELOGD</li>
                            </ul>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
```

But it always shows the normal menu, which is supposed to show when the user isn't logged in.

My goals by asking this question:

- Did I make any mistakes that could cause this problem.
- Is the code correct, if not, how to improve.

Thanks,

Wesley.

Comment: You have to start the session in the next file again! So your first line in your index.php file should be: session_start();

Comment: Have you started a session on the `index.php` page as well?

Comment: You need `session_start();` at the start of **both** pages.

Answer (score 1):

The `session_start()` needs to be at the BEGINNING of BOTH file, before any other code.

Comment: Technically, it just needs to be before any output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `session_start();` in every file in wehre your using the `$_SESSION` variable!

I would recommend you to put `session_start();` at the frist line of every file your using the `$_SESSION` variable (You don't have to put it on the frist line but before your using it!).

And if your menu is in `index.php` then it would look like this:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    ?>
        <ul class="submenu-holder">
            <li><a href="login.php">Inloggen</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Registreren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gebruikerslijst</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alle badges</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wachtwoord vergeten</a></li>
        </ul>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
        <ul class="submenu-holder">
            <li>INGELOGD</li>
        </ul>
    <?php
    }
?>
```